# Passing data to Segment control from Table view Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using table view cell to display the data . I have a segment control . In first section I am displaying the list of the move with button control . **When the user click the check mark  button I want to send those table  view cell values to seconds control and added to on it** .. Please give me some sample code based on the below code ..
Here is the table view cell .

```
import UIKit
    
    
    
    protocol CellSubclassDelegate: AnyObject {
        func buttonTapped(cell: MovieViewCell)
    }
    
    class MovieViewCell: UITableViewCell {
        
        weak var delegate:CellSubclassDelegate?
        
        static let identifier = "MovieViewCell"
        
    
        @IBOutlet weak var movieImage: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var movieTitle: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var movieOverview: UILabel!
        
        @IBOutlet weak var someButton: UIButton!
        
        
       
        @IBAction func someButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
            self.delegate?.buttonTapped(cell: self)
        }
        
        
        func configureCell(title: String?, overview: String?, data: Data?) {
            
            movieTitle.text = title
            movieOverview.text = overview
            
            movieImage.image = nil
            if let imageData = data{
                movieImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
               //  movieImage.image = nil
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Table View Cell for row code ..

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MovieViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MovieViewCell
        
        let row = indexPath.row
        let title = presenter.getTitle(by: row)
        let overview = presenter.getOverview(by: row)
        let baseImageURL = presenter.getUrlImage(by: row)
        let data = presenter.getImageData(by: baseImageURL)
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.configureCell(title: title, overview: overview, data: data)
        
       
        
        return cell
    }
```

Here is the code implementation of delegate .

```
extension MovieViewController : CellSubclassDelegate{
    func buttonTapped(cell: MovieViewCell) {
        guard (self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) != nil) else {return}
            let customViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MovieDeatilsViewController") as? MovieDeatilsViewController
        customViewController?.titlemovie = cell.movieTitle.text ?? ""
        customViewController?.imagemovie = cell.movieImage.image
        customViewController?.overview = cell.movieOverview.text ?? ""
     //   customViewController?.movieTitleHeader.text = cell.movieTitle.text ?? ""
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(customViewController!, animated: true)
                    
                   
    }
}
```

Did select methods implementation ..

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let dc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MovieDeatilsViewController") as! MovieDeatilsViewController
        
        let row = indexPath.row
       dc.titlemovie = presenter.getTitle(by: row) ?? ""
       dc.overview = presenter.getOverview(by: row) ?? ""
       
       let baseImageURL = presenter.getUrlImage(by: row)
       
       dc.imagemovie = UIImage(data: presenter.getImageData(by: baseImageURL)!)
       
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dc, animated: true)
   }
    
    
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the applications .

[image]

**When the user click check box I want to add those table view cell values into favourite segment control**

Comment: If I understand, when you chose a cell the movie becomes a favorite, so if you select favourite segment you see only the favourite movies ? If so you must use a filter on the movie list you use in dataSource method which will be all movies or favourite movies.

Comment: If you want 2 list you can also do it with 2 tableview at the same place and the segment control will show the selected only by setting isHidden property of table views

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot I have a check mark . When user click this check mark I want to add those cell values into favourites segment control . and also hide the check mark from selected cell . This is want I am trying to do . But I am not sure How can I pass the data @PtitXav

Comment: a segment control is a control to select one value (the segment number) . When you select a segment it calls it’s delegate a method to indicate that the value changed. It is up to the delegate to decide what to do when this happens. I suppose the delegate is the tableView controller or the view controller containing the table view and the segment control.

Comment: I have UITableViewCell class to contain the properties of the cell then I am passing those values by using delegate and didSelectRow methods to different controller and it working fine. I want to pass cell values into different table view cell when user clicked the button  with in segment control . This is what I am trying to achieve . As you said I need another table view cell to do it But I am not sure how can I pass it by using button control @PtitXav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am example of what you need to achieve (The name of method and variables are not the exact ones, it just to help you understand the principle). In this case with only one table view:

```
struct MoviePresenter {
    var nbRows: Int = 0
}

class MoviesVC  {
    var presenter = MoviePresenter()
    var tableViewSelect : UISegmentedControl!
    var movieTableView: UITableView!
    
    var favoriteMovies = [Int]() // the list of row of favorite movies
    
    // utility function to know if movie is favorite or not
    func isInFavorites(_ row: Int) -> Bool {
        return favoriteMovies.first(where: {$0 == row}) != nil
    }
    
    // Note : all table view datasource/delegate methods need to check
    // which is the current selected display
    func numberOfRowsInSection(_ section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableViewSelect.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            return presenter.nbRows
        } else {
            return favoriteMovies.count
        }
    }
    
    // in cellForRow
    func cellForRow(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableViewSelect.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            // default display
            let cell = UITableViewCell() // you dequeue your cell here
            // init cell for presenter (by: row)
            if isInFavorites(indexPath.row) {
                // checkMark handling
            }
            
            // to handle checkmark
            cell.tag = indexPath.row
        } else {
            // favorite list
            let cell = UITableViewCell() // you dequeue your favorite cell here
            let row = favoriteMovies[indexPath.row]

            // if you want to handle checkmark
            cell.tag = row
        }
    }
    
    func checkMarkTappedInFavoriteCell(cell: UITableViewCell) {
        let row = cell.tag
        // set/unset favorite check mark when tapped
        if isInFavorites(row) {
            favoriteMovies.removeAll(where: {$0 == row})
        } else {
            favoriteMovies.append(row)
        }
        movieTableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)], with: .none)
    }
    
    // action to be executed when selected segment changes
    @IBAction func tableViewSelectedIndexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        self.movieTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This only in the case you want only one table view. In case you want 2 table views the change in segmented control will also make one tableview visible and the other invisible.