# Swift Segment control with Table View Cell Data Passing techniques

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to pass the data from one table view cell to another one table view cell . I want to add those table view cell values to another segment control when user click the add the button . I have two table view with cell in same view controller . I am following delegate to implement it but I facing some issues .

**1. I used the isHide methods to hide the specific table view based on segment control selection , still show the both table views although I wanted to show one and both segment the same data is displaying .**

Here is the code .

```
@IBAction func selectSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        
       if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
           FavouriteTableView.isHidden = true
        setUpUI()
        presenter = MoviePresenter(view: self)
        presenter.getMovies()
           
        }
        
    }
```

**2. I want add the table view cell values to seconds table view cell when User clicked the button but actually not working .Here is the code for both table view cell .**

```
protocol CellSubclassDelegate: AnyObject {
    func buttonTapped(cell: MovieViewCell)
}

class MovieViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    weak var delegate:CellSubclassDelegate?
    
    static let identifier = "MovieViewCell"
    

    @IBOutlet weak var movieImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var movieTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var movieOverview: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var someButton: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBAction func someButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.buttonTapped(cell: self)
    }
    
    
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.delegate = nil
    }
    
    func configureCell(title: String?, overview: String?, data: Data?) {
        
        movieTitle.text = title
        movieOverview.text = overview
        
        movieImage.image = nil
        if let imageData = data{
            movieImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
           //  movieImage.image = nil
        }
    }
    
}
```

Code for second cell.

```
protocol CellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func AddFavourite(cell: FavouriteTableViewCell)
}

class FavouriteTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    weak var delegate:CellDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var FavouriteImage: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var FavouritemovieTitle: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var FavouritemovieOverview: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func NewMovie(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.AddFavourite(cell: self)
    }
    
}
```

Table view controller code implementation ..

```
class MovieViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var FavouriteTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
    
    private var presenter: MoviePresenter!
    
    var finalname = ""
    
   var movieTitle = ""
    var movieOverview = ""
    var movieImage : UIImage?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       userName.text = "Hello: " + finalname

       
    }
    private func setUpUI() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    
    
   private func searchBarText() {
        searchBar.delegate = self
    }
    
    @IBAction func selectSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        
       if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
           FavouriteTableView.isHidden = true
        setUpUI()
        presenter = MoviePresenter(view: self)
        presenter.getMovies()
           
        }
        
    }

extension MovieViewController: MovieViewProtocol {
    
    func resfreshTableView() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func displayError(_ message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let doneButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(doneButton)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}

extension MovieViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        presenter.rows
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MovieViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MovieViewCell
        
        let row = indexPath.row
        let title = presenter.getTitle(by: row)
        let overview = presenter.getOverview(by: row)
        let baseImageURL = presenter.getUrlImage(by: row)
        let data = presenter.getImageData(by: baseImageURL)
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.configureCell(title: title, overview: overview, data: data)
        return cell
        
    }
    

extension MovieViewController : CellSubclassDelegate{
    func buttonTapped(cell: MovieViewCell) {
        guard (self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) != nil) else {return}
            let customViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MovieDeatilsViewController") as? MovieDeatilsViewController
        customViewController?.titlemovie = cell.movieTitle.text ?? ""
        customViewController?.imagemovie = cell.movieImage.image
        customViewController?.overview = cell.movieOverview.text ?? ""
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(customViewController!, animated: true)
                    
                   
    }
}
extension MovieViewController :  CellDelegate{
    func AddFavourite(cell: FavouriteTableViewCell) {
        guard (self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) != nil) else {return}
        
        movieTitle = cell.FavouritemovieTitle.text ?? ""
        movieOverview = cell.FavouritemovieOverview.text ?? ""
        movieImage =  cell.FavouriteImage.image
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Here screenshot of the app desing.
[image: app design]

Here is the screenshot of the application .

[image]

Comment: Seems exactly like your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71187874/passing-data-to-segment-control-from-table-view-cell which you asked yesterday. Please don't repeat questions.

Comment: I tried to implement it but facing this issues now

Comment: I can't see you're controller conform to FavouriteTableViewCell?
did you call anywhere?

Comment: I have two table view with cell in same controller named view controller. I want to add the cell values to second table view cell when user click the add favourite button @RezaKhonsari

Comment: for MovieViewCell you set delegate to self in tableViewController, but for FavouriteTableViewCell you didn't set delegate to tableViewController

Comment: Yes this where I am not sure to call second Delegate and pass those values to to segment control and added on it @RezaKhonsari

Comment: I think you need to change your tableview datasource when each segment item tapped

Comment: for example: 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
you can say if tableView == FavouriteTableView { return favorites.count }

Comment: and continue this to all tableView delegate

Comment: Yes . This is where I am stuck and try to solve it but I am new to swift . Trying to learn it in more details @RezaKhonsari

Comment: I will write my answer for you, but you're question has more edge cases

Comment: I have to pass the table view cell to another cell when user click the add button. Also it needs to show to favourite segment control @RezaKhonsari

Comment: I want display first table view cell record when user click the first segment control . In first table view cell I have an button to add the movie into favourite list and this is favourite segment control. I have one view controller with two table view . Both table view has cell . This contains title , image etc @RezaKhonsari

Comment: @Amzad I know what do you mean, there are more problems in your code, for example you, you are not created a model for you're favorite movies and shows your favorite list to favoriteTableView, and also you are not separate tableViews in your delegate, if you want i can make answer to guide about this, it's on you're side to fix your problem based on my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code first of all you need model for favorite movies not saving it on global storage, like this one:

```
struct Movie {
    let title: String
    let overview: String
    let image: UIImage?
}
```

add your array model into your controller:

```
// append to this array when user taped on favorite button
var favorites = [Movie]()
```

separate each you're tableView inside of tableViewDelegate(it's better to use just one tableView for this case):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      if tableView == FavoriteTableView {
        return favorites.count
      } else {
        return presenter.rows
      }
 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == FavoriteTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FavouriteTableViewCell, for: indexPath) as! FavouriteTableViewCell
            cell.delegate = self // This cause favorite protocol method trigered
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MovieViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MovieViewCell
            let row = indexPath.row
            let title = presenter.getTitle(by: row)
            let overview = presenter.getOverview(by: row)
            let baseImageURL = presenter.getUrlImage(by: row)
            let data = presenter.getImageData(by: baseImageURL)
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.configureCell(title: title, overview: overview, data: data)
            return cell
        }
    }
```

and update other delegate methods like this if needed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242319/discussion-on-answer-by-reza-khonsari-swift-segment-control-with-table-view-cell).